# list.reverse() is not working

Tags: python, list, reverse

I honestly just don't understand why this is returning `None` rather than a reversed list:

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> print l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print l.reverse()
None
```

Why is this happening?  According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), I am doing nothing wrong.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`reverse` modifies the list in place and returns `None`. If you do

```
l.reverse()
print l
```

you will see your list has been modified.

Comment: Sure, but what is the reason for not just returning the list too instead of `None`? Since it's just a reference and not a copy of the list, it can't be too expensive...

Answer (score 11):

`L.reverse()` modifies L in place. As a general rule, Python builtin methods will either mutate or return something but not both

The usual way to reverse a list is to use

```
print L[::-1]
```

`reversed(L)` returns a `listreverseiterator object` which is fine for iterating over, but not so good if you really want a list

`[::-1]` is just a [normal slice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) - the step is `-1` so you get a copy starting from the end and ending with the start

Answer (score 6):

`list.reverse()` reverses the list in place. It doesn't return the reversed list. For that, use [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) function:

```
print reversed(l)
```

Or just use the extended slice notation:

```
print l[::-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

The docs say

> list.reverse() :  Reverse the elements of the list, in place.

*in place* means the original list gets changed, rather than returning a new list, so the return you ask it to print is `None`.